# Does anyone know if there is a generalization of symplectic Kodaira dimension beyond 4-manifolds?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, characteristic-classes, kodaira-dimension

I'm aware that in algebraic geometry, one has the Kodaira-Iitaka dimension, which generalizes the Kodaira dimension, but does anyone know if a correspondent generalization in the symplectic category exists?  Perhaps its definition involves the signs of the cup product of the symplectic canonical class $K_{\omega}$ with powers of $[\omega]$ higher than $1$?

Comment: I do not know about the Kodaira dimension, but I believe that some other birational aspects have been extended to dimension 6 by Tian-Jun Li, Yongbin Ruan and Weiyi Zhang.

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1175266207 , http://www.math.umn.edu/~akhmedov/FRG-Lec-2.pdf